# Can I turn off invoice autogeneration on paypalplus?

Tags: magento2, paypal

Can I turn off invoice autogeneration on PayPal plus?
when a user pays with a Paypal invoice is generated automatically and I don't want that, how can I turn it off?
from webhook I couldn't turn it off, nor from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following payment actions **Sale** to **Authorization** in paypal configuration in magento admin.

[image]

Comment: I am using PayPalPlus , not PayPal Express .